# How to authenticate user and send authenticated requests from client to server side in Firebase realtime database?

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have a client side React application which currently gets access of the current authenticated user through this:

```js
const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
    setCurrentUser(user);
});
```

Also we have realtime database rules in certain parts like

```
request.auth != null
```

Now, I'm planning to shift the firebase part to a NodeJS + express server.
For this I have installed the `firebase` SDK in my server. But is it safe to use the normal authentication functions from firebase SDK?

In client side app, only one user object could exist at a particular time. Whereas, in the server side, there could be several requests for authentication at the same time.

Also, even if I do the authentication, how am I going to send authenticated requests to perform CRUD operations on my realtime and firestore databases?

Note: I've heard about the `firebase-admin` SDK, but have also learnt that it's immensely powerful. That's why I want to avoid using it. If I have to use it, what is the right way to do so?

Comment: this may help: https://medium.com/litslink/firebase-admin-sdk-basics-in-examples-ee7e009a1116

Answer (score 1):

The recommended approach is explained here in the Authentication [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens?hl=en#web).

And yes you need to use the Admin SDK on your Node.js backend server.

Basically the mechanism is the following one:

1. You keep the user authentication in your React app, in other word you call the Firebase Authentication service to sign in the user (with the JavaScript SDK from your web app). Firebase creates an ID token that uniquely identifies the user. See this [section](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens?hl=en#retrieve_id_tokens_on_clients).
2. Then when the app interacts with your Node.js backend server you can send that ID token (a JWT) to your backend and validate it using the Firebase Admin SDK. The `verifyIdToken()` method is used to verify an ID token, as explained in this [section](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens?hl=en#verify_id_tokens_using_the_firebase_admin_sdk). The method returns the decoded ID token from which you get the user's uid.
3. With the user's uid you can query your Realtime and Firestore databases for the data corresponding to the user (again with the [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node)).

---

**IMPORTANT:** Note that the Admin SDK totally bypasses security rules. So it's up to you, in your Node.js code, to manage the access to the data corresponding to the user.

Comment: Hey @ShouryaShikhar, did you have the time to look at the proposed solution?